# Converting to and from CENTS

Tags: php, numbers, currency, money-format

So I know there have been multiple questions regarding Money and converting to and from cents. 
Heck I have even asked another one, but I want to make a slightly different question so I hope there are no duplicates out there.

So I have created a function that takes a Dollar Value and sends it to CENTS. 
But I think I have a slight problem with my code and hoping I can get it tweaked a little.

```
$money4 = "10.0001";
// Converted to cents, as you can see it's slightly off. 
$money41 = "1001";
// So when "1001", get's put in the database, and then I return it back as a Money variable. 
// We get, "$10.01"... but what I have now is a leak in my amounts... as it rounded up to the second point.
```

So to do what I have done, I have used to functions I made to do this.

```
// This essentially gets a DOLLAR figure, or the CENT's Figure if requested.    
function stripMoney($value, $position = 0, $returnAs = "") 
{   
    // Does it even have a decimal?
    if(isset($value) && strstr($value, ".")) {

        // Strip out everything but numbers, decimals and negative
        $value    = preg_replace("/([^0-9\.\-])/i","",$value);
        $decimals = explode(".", $value);

        // Return Dollars as default
        return ($returnAs == "int" ? (int)$decimals[$position] : $decimals[$position]);

    } elseif(isset($value)) {
        // If no decimals, lets just return a solid number
        $value = preg_replace("/([^0-9\.\-])/i","",$value);
        return ($returnAs == "int" ? (int)$value : $value);
    }
}
```

The next function I use is to generate the CENTS or return it back as dollars.

```
function convertCents($money, $cents = NULL, $toCents = TRUE)
{
    if(isset($money)) {
        if($toCents == TRUE) {
            // Convert dollars to cents
            $totalCents = $money * 100;
            // If we have any cents, lets add them on as well
            if(isset($cents)) {
                $centsCount = strlen($cents);
                // In case someone inputs, $1.1
                // We add a zero to the end of the var to make it accurate
                if($centsCount < 2) {
                    $cents = "{$cents}0";   
                }
                // Add the cents together
                $totalCents = $totalCents + $cents;
            }
            // Return total cents
            return $totalCents;

        } else {
            // Convert cents to dollars
            $totalDollars = $money / 100;
            return $totalDollars;
        }
    }
}
```

And the final function that puts everything together. So we just use 1 function to merge the 2 functions together basically.

```
function convertMoney($value, $toCents = TRUE) {
    if(isset($value) && strstr($value, ".")) {
        return convertCents(stripMoney($value, 0), stripMoney($value, 1), $toCents);

    } elseif(!empty($value)) {
        return convertCents(stripMoney($value, 0), NULL, $toCents);
    }
}
```

What I have done might be overkill, But I think it's fairly solid, other than this 1 detail, that I can see.

can anyone help me with these adjustments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use floating point arithmetic if you need exact answers. This applies to almost all languages, not just PHP. Read the big warning in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/float).

Instead check out [BC Math](http://php.net/bc) or the [GMP extension](http://php.net/gmp). The latter only works with integer numbers so you are probably most interested in BC Math.

Comment: your right, I was way overcomplicating it...all I really need to do is remove everything but, decimal points, store that in MySQL with DECIMAL field, and then use BCMath to figure out the rest.

Answer (score 2):

I think **[money_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php)** is the function you were looking for...

```
<?php

$number = 1234.56;

// let's print the international format for the en_US locale
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');
echo money_format('%i', $number) . "\n";
// USD 1,234.56

// Italian national format with 2 decimals`
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'it_IT');
echo money_format('%.2n', $number) . "\n";
// Eu 1.234,56

?>
```

Comment: yeah I can format my numbers alright, i'm just having a hard time getting my 4 decimal locations...